# C# object to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get an object from my web api service to my Cordova JS Mobile app. However, working with objects making things very hard for me right now.

In javascript side, i've tried to convert the object into JSON which is this:

```
{
    "Employee": {
        "Department": {
            "DepID": "1",
            "DepName": "Foo",
            "DepLevel": "5",
            "DepChief": "JDoe",
            "ChiefID": 2906
        },
        "Photo": "http://foo.com/heuheuhe.jpg",
        "name": "Mr.Amazing",
        "isActive": true,
        "region": null,
        "id": 1295,
        "title": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Worker"
        },
        "WorkedHours": 30,
        "Order": 14
    }
}
```

However, i have no idea how to work with this in Javascript. For example: I've tried to get photo of Employee and DepID values from in it(tried parsing this with JSON.Parse i think i misused it) and failed very hard. Since i have no clue how to use it tried many silly things and i am so lost right now.

Also, I tried to work with this without converting it into JSON at all but when I try to get a value like `alert(obj.Employee.Department.DepID);` I get an error. I wanted to see the object itself like `alert(obj);` all I see is object Object.

Comment: Why dont you simply return your object as json with Json()?

Comment: Are you saying that's what you got when you converted it into JSON, or that that's what you want to obtain? Have you tried looking at it in your browser's debugger?

Comment: use console.log(urjson); and hint , use for-in

Comment: @k4rlsson The service that i'm using is not actually all mine. So, they return objects.

Comment: @JLRishe i've got this when i converted it into JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is almost<sup>1</sup> JavaScript literal objects.

Therefore in JS:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

and then just access properties of `data`.

Eg.

```
var deptId = data.Employee.Department.DeptID
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The exception is handling some characters: the JSON rules are slightly different to JavaScript's.

Comment: 1 The exception is handling some characters: the JSON rules are slightly different to JavaScript's. This didn't actually solved my problem but i know how to fix it now. Thanks.